# Is it possible to get keydown event from browser address bar?

Tags: jquery, browser, event-handling, keydown, address-bar

I want to get the **jquery keydown event** when I type in browser address bar.
Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: Not possible, unless you are developing a plugin for a browser?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get keydown events from the browser's address bar because Address Bar is not a part of your HTML document, and hence you cannot attach events, unless you are developing some sort of Chrome plugin.

Comment: I heard about window.addEventListener to get browser onload like events... is it correct?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no event which can detect keystrokes on browser's URL bar. I revisited MDN's event reference guide and couldn't find anything.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events